# merge sorted lists

Tags: algorithm, merge, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to come up with a divide and conquer algorithm for merging j sorted lists with n number of elements but I'm stuck; I don't know how to divide this problem into smaller sub-problems. I want it to be more efficient that the merging algorithm that goes like this:

Merge the first two lists; then merge the resulting list with the third list; then merge the resulting list with the fourth list, etc. which takes O(j * jn).

Answer (score 0):

u can do it in O(j*log(j)n) time

```
while(n!=1)
    for i=0 to n/2
        merge list(i) with list list(n)
    n = n/2
```

that way u merge the whole group into pairs, then pairs of pairs and so on

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need divide and conquer to achieve this. You could just create one big list unordered then use built in sort to sort the big list which would be O(jn*Log(jn))

```
    List<int> returnList(List<List<int>> lists)
    {
        List<int> ret = new List<int>();
        for(int i=0;i<lists.Length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<lists;j++)
            {
                ret.Add(lists[i][j]);               
            }
        }
        ret.Sort();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no different from standard merge sort. Consider a list of size `jn` with unsorted items. After `log(n)` iterations of merge sort on the list of size `jn` items, you will have `j` sorted lists with `n` items in each list. So just continue on with merge sort to solve your problem.

Please look up merge sort, which is a divide-and-conquer algorithm, and understand it. Then you will be able to solve this problem easily.